# Dummy Table of Dates and Hour in T-SQL

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I want to build a dummy table that has every single date for the year and every hour of the day. My code below creates a table of dates, and creates a table of hours separately. How do I change my date table so that each date shows up 24 times before moving onto the next date, so that I can join the two tables together?

Let me know if you can think of a more efficient way to do this.

Date table

```
CREATE TABLE _Dates 
(
    d DATE,
    PRIMARY KEY (d)
)

DECLARE @dIncr DATE = '2018-01-01'
DECLARE @dEnd DATE = '2018-12-31'

WHILE (@dIncr < @dEnd)
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO _Dates (d) 
    VALUES (@dIncr)

    SELECT @dIncr = DATEADD(DAY, 1, @dIncr)
END

SELECT * FROM _Dates
DROP TABLE _Dates
```

Hours table

```
SELECT [Hour] = 0 
INTO #hour

CREATE TABLE #hour (h numeric)

INSERT INTO #hour 
VALUES (0), (1), (2), (3), (4), (5), (6), (7), (8),
       (9), (10), (11), (12), (13), (14), (15), (16),
       (17), (18), (19), (20), (21), (22), (23)
```

Comment: You can just cross join your two tables to get what you want: `SELECT _dates.d, #hour.h FROM _dates, #hours;`

Comment: I'd recommend recursion

Comment: you can view this url. Depending on your environment esp in DW flat is preferred.
https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/647950/Create-and-Populate-Date-Dimension-for-Data-Wareho

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can be done via an ad-hoc tally table

I suspect more performant than recursion  (8,760 rows in 0.305 seconds)

**Example**

```
Declare @Date1 datetime = '2018-01-01'
Declare @Date2 datetime = '2019-01-01'
Select Top (DateDiff(HOUR,@Date1,@Date2)+1) D=DateAdd(HOUR,-1+Row_Number() Over (Order By (Select Null)),@Date1) 
 From  master..spt_values n1,master..spt_values n2
```

**Returns**

```
D
2018-01-01 00:00:00.000
2018-01-01 01:00:00.000
2018-01-01 02:00:00.000
2018-01-01 03:00:00.000
...
2018-12-31 21:00:00.000
2018-12-31 22:00:00.000
2018-12-31 23:00:00.000
2019-01-01 00:00:00.000
```

Comment: Really? old-style joins?

Comment: @SMor  Does it really matter in this case?

Comment: Don't you need a ORDER BY if you're going to use TOP? Answer was correct in this case, but not guaranteed.

Comment: @EdCallahan Order by is not necessary... the Row_Number() portion will do that for you.

Comment: Oh, I see that now. It doesn't matter what values are returned from the FROM, only that you have the correct number of them. Very nice.

Comment: @EdCallahan BINGO.   :)

Answer (score 2):

I'll put in a plug for keeping a numbers table around for things like this. Just a table with a sequence of ints, with a primary key on that field.

```
declare @Date1 datetime = '2018-01-01'
Declare @Date2 datetime = '2019-01-01'

select dateadd(hour, n, @Date1)
    from Numbers
    where n <= DateDiff(HOUR,@Date1,@Date2)
```

Comment: I should have stressed the usefulness of actually having a numbers table.  +1

Comment: Even with the Numbers table, the TOP and ROW_NUMBER strategy performs better on my system. Our Numbers table is pretty big, nearly 80 million rows, so that is a factor. On my system the WHERE statement causes an index seek, while the TOP causes a scan. Because of the relative size of the result set versus the index size, the scan performs a lot better (percent wise, in actual time they bother perform fine). YMMV depending on size of Numbers table, etc.

Comment: 80MM seems a bit excessive, but I suspect better than too small.  The n1,n2 will generate a max of 63MM observations,